# WCF System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<> does not contain a defintion for the method Close() inside a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, uwp

In implementing a WCF Service, I created a wrapper class called `ServiceClient` that inherits from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`:

```
public class ServiceClient<T> : ClientBase<T> where T : class
    {
        private bool _disposed;

        public ServiceClient(Binding binding, EndpointAddress address) : base(binding, address)
        {
        }

        public T Proxy => Channel;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed) return;
            if (!disposing) return;
            if (State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Close(); // Error
                }
                catch
                {
                    Abort();
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

This implementation worked fine until I decided that I wanted to use it inside a UWP application. The UWP application required my Class Library to become a Portable Class Library. I created a Portable Class Library targeting .NET 4.5 and Windows 10 and re-added all my source files.

Afterwards, the build fails with the following error:

`The name 'Close' does not exist in the current context`

pointing to the `Close()` method inside the try-catch block of my `ServiceClient Dispose(bool)`. Also, a `using` block inside my UWP application produces an error stating that my `ServiceClient` does not implement `IDisposable` now.

Why is there such a difference between the two implementations of `ClientBase<T>` between a Class Library and a Portable Class Library? Is there any way for me to solve this issue?

Comment: It seems we can use the WCF Service by the "Add Service Reference", we do not need to use it in Library.